# What's your preferred approach to the sortable ObservableCollection in WPF?

Tags: wpf

This article "[Write a Sortable ObservableCollection for WPF](http://elegantcode.com/2009/05/14/write-a-sortable-observablecollection-for-wpf/)" appears to be all that's needed (for me) to handle any need to sort `ObservableCollection`. However, there might be scenarios that need a more complex design. Or, on the other extreme, there may be a way to prevent this need for a sort by design. Am I on the right track here or is this question moot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on whether you are trying to persist the user-selected ordering, like if the user is prioritizing items.

If the sorting is for display purposes only as is more common, [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=VS.90).aspx) and [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=VS.90).aspx) are well-adapted to sorting and filtering collections in various ways in the WPF UI.

Comment: Ah, yes, the nedd to sort sort `ObservableCollection` is more of a Silverlight issue since `CollectionView` and `CollectionViewSource` have not been fully supoorted in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

I have created one application that allows you to Sort, filter, implace editing based on User interaction.

http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html

You can check this out, it might help. Sorted ObservableCollection is basically very expensive.